# How to terminate a cat pipe command in shell script?

Tags: shell

I use a command like to cat a pipe file and grep some data. A simple code such as,

```
temp=""
temp=$(cat file|grep "some data"| wc -c)
if [ $temp -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "I got data"
fi
```

The file is a pipe(FIFO), it will output data and not stop. How can i to terminate the command of cat pipe in a finite time?

Comment: What is condition upon which you want to stop reading file?

Comment: Some string data, but the problem is the command will not stop. It's blocking in cat file.

Comment: I don't see when it _should_ stop. If on first occurance of 'some data', then wc is overkill - and you need something like perl -ne 'print if not /somedata/ or exit' file. If not, then when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep|wc` is the wrong tool for this job.  Choose a better one, such as `sed`,

```
if sed -n -e '/some data/q;$q1' file; then
    ....
fi
```

`awk`,

```
found=$(awk '/some data/{print"y";exit}' file)
if [ -n "$found" ]; then
    ....
fi
```

or `sh` itself.

```
found=
while read line; do
    if expr "$line" : ".*some data" >/dev/null; then
        found=y
        break
    fi
done <file
if [ -n "$found" ]; then 
    ....
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it adding $ to temp variable in line 3:

```
if [ $temp -gt 0 ]
```

Because you want to compare temp value, and you get it using $ before the variable.

About file "pipe", you can execute cat until you get a specific string.
I mean, you can use cat for reading and stop when you receive, for example, a "\n".

I will give you an example that you can run in your terminal:

```
cat > example_file.txt << EOF
hello
I'm a example filen
EOF
```

cat will be reading from standard input untill you enter "EOF". And then, the content of the file will be:

```
cat example_file.txt 
hello
I'm an example file
```

So this way you can read by chunks, for example, lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the exit status of `grep` itself:

```
if grep -q "some data" file; then
    echo "I got data"
fi
```

The `-q` prevents anything from being written to standard output if a match is found.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by using shell script.

```
cat <some file and conditions> &
< perform your task>

kill $(pidof cat)
```

This works as long as you have one instance of "cat" running at a time.

Comment: pidof is not portable

Answer (score 0):

You can use `timeout` command, which is part of `coreutils`.

`man timeout`:

```
NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
...
```

To wait 10 seconds:

```sh
temp=$(timeout 10 cat file|grep "some data"| wc -c)
if [ $temp -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "I got data"
fi
```